# amd keyid microsoftaik.azure.net does not exist

Tags: windows, drivers, windows-11, amd

I have read all posts about this, try every solution and nothing work. To sum up, currently I have:

- clean install of Windows 11 Pro (legit activation)
- all updates applied
- The TPM module is on and
- the following security settings:

  [image: gotqn_2-1697090067440.png]

  and this one:

  [image: gotqn_1-1697090067582.png]

I have tried with all options disabled and with Windows 10, but nothing changed, so I believe there is no working workaround currently and no fix (neither from Microsoft and AMD).

The hardware:

[image]

and more:

[image: gotqn_3-1697090067651.png]

Before this installation ,I have performed BIOS updates, so we can say that currently everything possible is updated. And still, I am constantly getting the following errors:

*SCEP Certificate enrollment initialization for Local system via https://AMD-KeyId-907d65e9b562315997dd5ad086b2b7598957b92c.microsoftaik.azure.net/templates/Aik/scep failed:
GetCACaps
GetCACaps: Not Found
{"Message":"The authority "amd-keyid-907d65e9b562315997dd5ad086b2b7598957b92c.microsoftaik.azure.net" does not exist."}
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Date: Sun, 08 Oct 2023 17:20:05 GMT
Content-Length: 121
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000;includeSubDomains
x-ms-request-id: b01f3262-9f89-4da6-8d60-15c81efbc9bd
Method: GET(359ms)
Stage: GetCACaps
Not found (404). 0x80190194 (-2145844844 HTTP_E_STATUS_NOT_FOUND)*

Note that the system restarts frequently (no matter if I am playing, using Hyper-V, or just turn on the PC and do nothing).

I would appreciate any help as currently the PC is useless which is bad including several weeks of debugging.

What makes the situation even worse is that I try to post the above information in the AMD forum several times and each time someone marked the post as spam.

Actually, it is kind of difficult to find help in the web as one needs to check the windows event viewer errors and to search for this particular error. For me, before that, I checked the PC RAM, the SSDs, clean the PC Box form dust and check all power cable as usually this restarts are connected with hardware issues.

Comment: A workstation that restarts frequently after Windows has been installed, with no information in the system event log is likely a hardware failure. This is more of a SuperUser question.

Comment: There is information in the event log. I have posted the exact type of errors. Basically, they are only two - come one after another. If you search by the error I have posted (as it is the same for all users) you can find various threads (https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/scep-certificate-enrollment-initialization-for/d7c4cfda-9573-49a9-8479-d6e77406dafe). The issue is, at this moment no workaround works.

Comment: Doesn't matter if the events were "posted somewhere". System Center Endpoint Protection (SCEP) is a bright shiny object that you are focused on, and isn't part of Windows or related to restarts.

Comment: @GregAskew I have tested the RAM and the SSDs. Do you believe I need to focus on testing somehow the other components? For example the motherboard, the GPU?

Comment: Did you ever figure out what was causing this? I've run into a similar situation.